# Two parallel lines of stars

Tags: amateur-observing

I’m in New Zealand and have just seen two lines of uniform stars in parallel lines moving slowly from east and disappearing into nothing right above us. They went on for nearly two minutes before the last one vanished and were not like the star link satellites that move in one tight line from horizon to horizon, they were more spaced out and coming from far off and disappearing into somewhere above us. Also it looked like a shooting star came out of the line and one of the stars was them missing from the uniform lines. Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Hi thanks no the lights I saw were quite different to the star link line which I’ve seen a few times now, these seemed much further away and were spaced out evenly and two lines rather than one like star link. Also they seemed to disappear into nothing in the middle of the sky(no clouds) where as star link disappeared over the horizon. Thanks

Comment: Probably still starlink

Comment: Starlink satellites move into higher, less uniform orbits a few weeks after launch, and have been launched in groups of 60 about once per month. All satellites vanish when they enter Earth's shadow.

Comment: @grahamewalker-cudby If you update the question and include a specific date and time it may be possible to verify if a group of Starlink satellites passed over. Once you've added the information can you ping me with a comment? Maybe the question needs more scrutiny and can be reopened. *Thanks!*

Comment: Hi thanks for that, yea been doing some reading and come to that conclusion, they weren’t on the star link tracker but Seems that the earlier launches ones are supposed to become invisible to the naked eye once spread out and high, I must have been lucky with the perfect night and angle of view to catch a quick glimps of some of the early ones in the last of suns light. On another note I got a good look at comet Swan thismorning! Amazing. Thanks for your help.